# No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.plus() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/searchpage?s=]

Tags: groovy, geb

I am getting this error for a geb test using `loadData()`

```
No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.plus() is applicable for argument 

types: (java.lang.String) 
values: [/searchpage?s=] 
Possible solutions: plus(java.util.Map), plus(java.util.Collection), values(), put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), is(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

The Code:

```
@Test
void canDoSearch() {
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1100, 1080));
    def url = browser.config.rawConfig.baseUrl + "/searchpage?s=" + terms[rand.nextInt(terms.length)]
    go url
    $("#productsSortBy").click()
    $("form").sortBy='newest'
    waitFor{!$(".ajax-loading")}
    at SearchResultsPage
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Test
    void canDoSearch(){
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1100, 1080));
        def url = browser.config.rawConfig.baseUrl + "/searchpage?s=" + terms[rand.nextInt(terms.length)]
        go url
        $("#productsSortBy").click()
        $("form").sortBy='newest'
        waitFor{!$(".ajax-loading")}
         at SearchResultsPage

Comment: In the future, please edit your post to add code, or you know, just add it in there when you initially ask the question.

Comment: Why are you building the url by hand instead of using the [advanced `Page` navigation feature](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#advanced-page-navigation) instead?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `browser.config.rawConfig.baseUrl` is not a String. Try calling `toString()` on that.